# How to use integer for money field in the database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, type-conversion

I've used integer for price field in the database, when I store 28.8808 in the field it rounded and precision scales up **(28.8808 = 29)**
How do I keep the 2 or 4 decimal points. without decimal data type.
thanks

Comment: One way would be keeping the integer and fractional parts in two different fields if you don't want to use `DECIMAL` data type. But curious mind wants to know why don't you want to use `DECIMAL` datatype?

Comment: Because calculations, I used decimal but when inserting in the database it got changed the format I was specified was (10,4) and when inserting 55400 it was stored as 55.0000

Comment: I think it is a problem with your integer format number (in your python/php/... code). I think you generate query where price  is '55 400' or 55,400. Correct version for 55400 should be 55400 :).

Answer (score 1):

If you need precision like that: 1.23 you can save your prices like that:

```
UPDATE prices SET price = (1.23*100) WHERE priceid = X;
```

and read prices using sth like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(price/100,2) FROM prices WHERE priceid = X ;
```

If you need better precision you need to multiply 100 by 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
$getRate = DB::table('currency_rates')
     ->select('crt_id','buy_rate')
     ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
        $rate = $getRate->buy_rate;
        $c_price = $unit_price*$rate;
        $expense->c_price = number_format($c_price, 4);
        $expense->c_total = number_format($quantity*$c_price, 4);
        $expense->rate_id = $getRate->crt_id;
```

c_price and c_total are not stored as expected gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$c_prices = ['55400', '55.400', '55 400', '55,400'];
foreach($c_prices as $c_price)
print (string)$c_price . ' => ' . number_format((float)$c_price, 4) . PHP_EOL;
```

prints:

```
55400 => 55,400.0000 [!!!] 55400
55.400 => 55.4000    [OK]  55.4
55 400 => 55.0000    [!!!] 55.0
55,400 => 55.0000    [!!!] 55.0
```

if you'd like to print 55400 as 55400.0000 instead 55,400.0000 you should modify your code:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

number_format($yourVal, 4, '.', ''); // $thousands_sep = '';
```

Comment: still 55400 is stored as 55.0000

Comment: Please share 1. your insert / update code; 2. query result (from mysqlclient, phpmyadmin): first: SHOW CREATE TABLE currency_rates;     and second: SELECT * FROM currency_rates ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: I solved it by increasing the digits (10,4) to (19,4) and know its working fine. Thank you anyway.